# Bind properties to html template to reduce html code

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout observable with a large list of properties. I currently have a lot of repeated html, that basically is the same apart from the property name. Is there any way I can use the equivalent of for/in with knockout templates?

I have a number of fields (approx. 20) that I want to display in a bootstrap form so each of them will use the following html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label data-bind="text: $parent.locale.fields.XYZ" for="XYZ" class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input data-bind="value: XYZ" type="text" name="XYZ" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Where XYZ is the name of the field. Is there any way I can loop through each property so that I do not have to repeat the html code for each field?

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/mSYZj/. Please note that my fields are not really called field1, field2 etc. so I cannot use a numerical loop.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/KR9GG/

Comment: Excellent - that's pretty much it. Edited the fiddle to do the for= and name= attributes (http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/KR9GG/1/). Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Object.keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff688127%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) (only IE9+) to get the property names of a given object.

Then you can use this in a `foreach` where you can use the `$data` to access the property name and use the array indexer syntax to get to your observables:

```
<form data-bind="foreach: Object.keys(data())" role="form">    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label data-bind="text: $parent.locale.fields[$data], 
                          attr: { for: [$data] }" 
             class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input data-bind="value: $parent.data()[$data], 
                          attr: { name: [$data] }" 
                 type="text" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" />
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/KR9GG/1/).

In production you probably don't want to use `Object.keys` directly in your binding but you can generate the property name array within your viewmodel (you can also exclude some of the properties etc.).

Comment: Thanks - good idea about using a property name array. This means I can restrict the form to only certain fields (e.g. not the title). Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/KR9GG/2/